# Is this ODE-integral problem solvable?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have stumbled on a problem that I have absolutely no idea how to solve. It may even be unsolvable, or it may make no sense. I am not sure how to tell.
I have theis system of ODE's:

For variables $k(t), c(t)$, and constants $\rho, \theta, g, n$:

$$\dot k=k^{-\frac{2}{3}}-c(t)-(n+g)k$$

$$\dot c=(k^{-\frac{2}{3}}-\rho - \theta g)\cdot \frac{c(t)}{\theta}$$

The problem is that I must find out whether given these ODE's the following equation holds:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}x(\tau)d\tau=1, \text{where } x(t)=\frac{1}{3}k^{-\frac{2}{3}}$$

In principle it should hold for any $k(0), c(0)$, but lets say $k(0)=c(0)=1$.

**Can this problem even possibly be answered? Does it even make sense? I'm not** **sure how to know. If it is possible, how to do it, or what is the solution?**

ps. I would be ok with a numerical solution.

---

I just answered the question myself. It turns out not to depend much on the ODE at all. I only need a quite loose assumption (given in my answer).

**Followup question: What is the minimal assumption needed (instead of "Assumption 1", to make sure this conclusion is correct?**

Comment: Possibly use integration by parts and the information about the derivatives of k and c given to see if the integral equality holds? Did you stumble upon this in a homework sheet?

Comment: No, I pseudo-rigorously derived/speculated that it must hold. It is not from a homework sheet.

Comment: Does this have nothing to do with [this recently asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254552/solving-solow-differential-equation)? The similarities are striking.

Comment: yes that's a simpler version of the model, but his question is a standard question whereas mine is a non-standard speculation.

Comment: @Paul, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I may have an answer now to my own question that turns out to be **much** simpler than I thought.

It does not even depend on the ODE at all. 
We simply do integration by parts on

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}x(\tau)d\tau $$
as follows: 
$$\frac \delta {\delta \tau}e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}=-e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}\cdot \frac \delta {\delta \tau}\left(\int_0^\tau x(s)ds\right)$$

Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$=-e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}\cdot  x(\tau)$$

Now integrate both sides w.r.t $\tau$ from $0$ to $\infty$ and multiply by $-1$:
$$-e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}\bigg|_0^\infty=\int _0^\infty e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}\cdot  x(\tau)d\tau$$

The right hand side is what we want to evaluate and the left hand side is equal to:
$$\lim_{\tau \to \infty}(-e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds})+e^0$$

**Assumption 1.** Now if we assume $x(s)$ tends to a positive number as $s$ tends to infinity, then this limit is equal to $\lim_{\tau \to \infty}(-e^{-\tau})=0$

This gives 
$$\int _0^\infty e^{-\int_0^\tau x(s)ds}\cdot  x(\tau)d\tau=1$$

Independent of the ODE.

---

**Followup question: What is the minimal assumption needed (instead of "Assumption 1"), to make sure this conclusion is correct?**